# (Python code not working in loop) pandas.DataFrame.apply() not working in loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have a piece of code which works fine alone, but when I put it in loop (or use `df.apply()` method), it does not work.
The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
datadf=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X1','X2'])
for i in datadf.index.values.tolist():
    row=datadf.loc[i]
    x1=row['X1']
    x2=row['X2']
    set1=set([x1,x2])
    links=data2[data2['Xset']==set1]
    df1=pd.DataFrame(range(1,11),columns=['year'])
    def idlist1(row,var1):
        year=row['year']
        id1a=links[(links['xx1']==var1) & (links['year']==year)]
        id1a=id1a['id1'].values.tolist()
        id1b=links[(links['xx2']==var1) & (links['year']==year)]
        id1b=id1b['id2'].values.tolist()
        id1=list(set(id1a+id1b))
        return id1
    df1['id1a']=df1.apply(partial(idlist1,var1=x1),axis=1)
    #...(do other stuffs to return a value using "df1")
    del df1
```

Here `data2` is another dataframe. Here I'm trying to match the values of `(x1,x2)` to `data2`.
The code works fine outside the loop by which I mean, I specify `(x1,x2)` directly. But when I put the code in the loop or use `df.apply`, I always get the error message

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1)
```

I don't understand why. Could someone help? Thanks! 
(BTW, the version of `pandas` is `0.18.0`.)
The full error message is:

```
File "<ipython-input-229-541c0f3a4d2f>", line 19, in <module>
df1['id1a']=df1.apply(partial(idlist1,var1=x1),axis=1)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4042, in apply
return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",  line 4155, in _apply_standard
result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 223, in __init__
mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 359, in _init_dict
return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5250, in _arrays_to_mgr
return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3933, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
construction_error(len(arrays), arrays[0].shape, axes, e)

File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3895, in construction_error
raise e

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1)
```

**Update**: I found out the `df.apply` method somehow is not compatible with the loop, so I converted all the `apply`'s in the loop to loops, and the code works fine now. Although I "sort of" solved the issue, but I'm still very confused about why this would happen. If anyone knows why, I'd really appreciate the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please show the full error msg including which line is responsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because there're multiple definitions of `row`, one as an argument of the function `def idlist1(row,var1):` and one defined as `row=datadf.loc[i]`, you can try to rename one and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I tried, and renaming does not work.

Comment: @user18243 well.. tough luck, there's no much I can do without knowing the values of the variables, maybe you can add some plausible data coded manually and post it? (and I guess there's a great chance that you get the bug while you're doing so :)

Comment: As you suggested, I tried the code with some artificially constructed data, and the loop works. So I thought it should be the data problem. But then I "translated" the `def` and `apply` part inside the loop to another loop, and it works with the original data. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: @user18243 glad to know, and you've learned test-driven development lol.